# am I using the correct way to send a ping frame with websocket

Tags: typescript, websocket, netty

I am using netty `implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.65.Final'` as my websocket server, now I want to add heartbeat for the application. What I am trying to do is send a ping message from client side and back with the pong message from the server side. Now I am facing a problem that the server side always treat the client ping message as plain text frame, not a control frame. This is the server side code looks like:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (null != msg && msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {
        FullHttpRequest request = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
        String uri = request.uri();
        Map paramMap=getUrlParams(uri);
        if(uri.contains("?")){
            String newUri=uri.substring(0,uri.indexOf("?"));
            System.out.println(newUri);
            request.setUri(newUri);
        }
    }else if(msg instanceof TextWebSocketFrame){
        TextWebSocketFrame frame=(TextWebSocketFrame)msg;
    }else if(msg instanceof PingWebSocketFrame){
        PingWebSocketFrame frame=(PingWebSocketFrame)msg;
    }
    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
}
```

the code always run into `TextWebSocketFrame`, I have tried send ping message from client side like this:

```
const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (chatWebsocket && chatWebsocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                const pingFrame = new ArrayBuffer(2);
                const pingView = new DataView(pingFrame);
                pingView.setInt8(0, 0x89);
                pingView.setInt8(1, 0);
                chatWebsocket.send(pingFrame);
            }
        }, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
```

and like this:

```
const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (chatWebsocket && chatWebsocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
               
                chatWebsocket.send('Ping');
            }
        }, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
```

and I also tried this:

```
const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (chatWebsocket && chatWebsocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                
                chatWebsocket.send('ping');
            }
        }, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
```

also tried this:

```
 const heartbeatInterval = setInterval(() => {
                if (chatWebsocket && chatWebsocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    
                    chatWebsocket.send('');
                }
            }, HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS);
```

None of then could work. what should I do to make it work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Ping message as an instance of Netty `PingWebSocketFrame` and send it. Something similar to the code sample below.

```
    /**
     * Send a ping message to the server.
     *
     * @param buf content of the ping message to be sent.
     */
    public void sendPing(ByteBuffer buf) throws InterruptedException {
        if (channel == null) {
            // Handle this.
        }
        channel.writeAndFlush(new PingWebSocketFrame(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buf))).sync();
    }
```